# Should I reinstall the operating system on Mac Book Pro if I get lots of crashes?

Tags: macos, finder, pdf, crash, adobe

I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 on my Mac Book Pro Retina 15" early 2013 and find that starting back around Mavericks, my Adobe Acrobat Pro X and now XI crashes frequently.  Sometimes with Yosemite, I also see the finder crashing.  I'm not seeing issues with other applications.  I visited the genius bar today and the person there suggested to re-image my computer.  I'm hesitant to do this because it is a big time commitment and I'm not convinced it will resolve the issue.  I would have to back up everything and deactivate all my software, re-image, and then reinstall all my software.  I imagine this would take around 5 hours to complete all those steps.

I report the crash to apple each time it occurs, but not sure that has any effect, as I've been reporting for a long time now, and it still persists.

Is this likely a corruption of the operating system that a reinstall would fix or is this just a bug that would return upon re-image?  If it is a corruption of the OS, is there any other way to repair without doing a clean install that would take me many hours?

Here is a portion of an example report:

```
Process:               AdobeAcrobat [17873]
Path:                  /Applications/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro/Adobe Acrobat Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/AdobeAcrobat
Identifier:            com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro
Version:               11.0.10 (11.0.10)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           AdobeAcrobat [17873]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-04-18 15:17:53.952 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C1514)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        7B757609-35C3-B7BB-84EC-1AC63CF2BA4E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       45283618-7C54-421C-A586-690BB5BFB1CA

Time Awake Since Boot: 520000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       320 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::exception: std::exception

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9626169a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a09ff19 pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x96067eee abort + 156
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x906412f9 abort_message + 169
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x90664483 default_terminate_handler() + 272
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x90661ac0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 14
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x906614db __cxa_throw + 122
7   com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.TouchUp 0x16811d15 0x16732000 + 916757
8   com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.TouchUp 0x169ef3ae 0x16732000 + 2872238
9   com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.TouchUp 0x169d4e43 0x16732000 + 2764355
10  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.TouchUp 0x169d7aa1 0x16732000 + 2775713
11  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.TouchUp 0x169d7848 0x16732000 + 2775112
12  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.TouchUp 0x16972070 0x16732000 + 2359408
13  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.TouchUp 0x1697170f 0x16732000 + 2357007
14  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.TouchUp 0x16971651 0x16732000 + 2356817
15  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.TouchUp 0x1696800f 0x16732000 + 2318351
16  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x012a74bd AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 15701471
17  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x01192d24 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 14569030
18  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x011940a7 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 14574025
19  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x00e54213 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 11166517
20  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x00e51981 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 11156131
21  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.Comments    0x0aaa31ef 0xa8ad000 + 2056687
22  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.Comments    0x0aaa4b66 0xa8ad000 + 2063206
23  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.Comments    0x0aad7510 0xa8ad000 + 2270480
24  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.Comments    0x0aae0856 0xa8ad000 + 2308182
25  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.Comments    0x0aca9c29 0xa8ad000 + 4181033
26  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.Comments    0x0aca81f7 0xa8ad000 + 4174327
27  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.AcroForm    0x1b76510c 0x1b3cf000 + 3760396
28  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.DigSig  0x16dcbeb8 0x16db6000 + 89784
29  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x01191dce AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 14565104
30  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x0069e235 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3081047
31  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x0069f445 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3085671
32  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x006aedc5 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3149543
33  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x0069f7a7 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3086537
34  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x00ae47c3 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 7563493
35  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.Comments    0x0aa0c3dd 0xa8ad000 + 1438685
36  com.adobe.AcrobatPlugin.Scan    0x0b4c91cf 0xb4c3000 + 25039
37  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x0069165d AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3028863
38  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x0073a880 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3721634
39  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x0073a921 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3721795
40  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x0097bc5e AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 6086016
41  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x006da2f8 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3327002
42  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x006da456 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 3327352
43  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x00c0cec6 AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 8777704
44  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x00c0a95a AcroSecurityBailOutImpl + 8768124
45  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x003361b8 RunAcrobat + 3282588
46  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9836d853 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
47  com.apple.AppKit                0x96f163de __36-[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke + 51
48  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x92806c03 _os_activity_initiate + 89
49  com.apple.AppKit                0x96d88b57 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 602
50  com.apple.AppKit                0x96da4c19 -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 479
51  com.apple.AppKit                0x96da48fe -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 162
52  com.apple.AppKit                0x96da3f8a -[NSMenu _performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:sendAccessibilityNotification:] + 79
53  com.apple.AppKit                0x9711c7bb __38-[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:]_block_invoke + 52
54  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x92806c03 _os_activity_initiate + 89
55  com.apple.AppKit                0x96df5cdf -[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] + 141
56  com.apple.AppKit                0x96df5c3e -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 45
57  com.apple.AppKit                0x96df5c05 -[NSMenuItem _internalPerformActionThroughMenuIfPossible] + 106
58  com.apple.AppKit                0x96df5a52 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 120
59  com.apple.AppKit                0x96d99667 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 679
60  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9afea624 _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 36
61  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ae34651 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 2291
62  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ae3362c SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 402
63  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9ae46e65 SendEventToEventTarget + 88
64  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9afea4a2 SendHICommandEvent(unsigned long, HICommand const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned char, void const*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventRef**) + 447
65  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9aeab1fc SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 72
66  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9aeab1a8 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 207
67  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9aeab06c FinishMenuSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*) + 145
68  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9b041c96 MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned long, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) + 775
69  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9aeb239a _HandleMenuSelection2 + 512
70  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9aeb2184 _HandleMenuSelection + 55
71  com.apple.AppKit                0x96d186ab _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 359
72  com.apple.AppKit                0x96ba35f1 _DPSNextEvent + 1702
73  com.apple.AppKit                0x96ba2a71 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 186
74  com.apple.AppKit                0x96b9502c -[NSApplication run] + 907
75  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x000164d2 RunAcrobat + 6582
76  com.adobe.Acrobat.framework     0x00014c4f RunAcrobat + 307
77  com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro           0x00005ed5 main + 91
78  com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro           0x00005e71 start + 53

  [...]

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 30
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 6662655
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=362.8M resident=132.3M(36%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=230.5M(64%)
Writable regions: Total=557.5M written=183.3M(33%) resident=316.4M(57%) swapped_out=148K(0%) unallocated=241.1M(43%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
ATS (font support)                 32.2M
Activity Tracing                   2048K
CG backing stores                  32.5M
CG image                           1924K
CG shared images                    624K
CoreAnimation                      32.6M
CoreAnimation (reserved)              4K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
CoreGraphics                          8K
CoreImage                            72K
CoreUI image data                   676K
Foundation                            4K
IOKit                             102.8M
Image IO                            144K
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                            344.5M
MALLOC (admin)                       48K
Memory Tag 242                       12K
Memory Tag 249                      156K
OpenCL                               76K
OpenGL GLSL                         128K
Stack                              78.3M
VM_ALLOCATE                        18.9M
__DATA                             23.8M
__GLSLBUILTINS                     2588K
__IMAGE                             528K
__IMPORT                             24K
__LINKEDIT                         54.2M
__OBJC                             5056K
__TEXT                            308.6M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                       524.2M
shared memory                        68K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                               1.5G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      1.5G


Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B07, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.159.13.12)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: C-Media USB Audio Device
USB Device: Composite Device
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

You can see the [complete report here](http://public.rchius.com/AppleAdobeCrashLog.txt), which is too big to include in this question.

---

I don't have a reliable way to cause either the Finder or Acrobat to crash.  The Finder crashes are much rarer.  For Acrobat, I do notice a couple patterns:

1. Crashes sometimes occur just after saving the document (this is the case for the above crash report).
2. Crashes sometimes occur related to adding text to the document via the `Add Text` tool under Content Editing.

In either case, it seems that mouse movements might trigger the issue and thus I think I might be reducing the probability of crashing by avoiding mouse movements for a bit after either of the above two actions.

---

[Here is the Etre Check report](http://public.rchius.com/EtreCheck.txt) for my system.

Comment: Do you use an Apple mouse or a third party? It might also help to run [EtreCheck](http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck) on your Mac, then paste the results into a [Gist](https://gist.github.com) and add a link to the Gist in your question. It could be a third party extension or plugin that is loading itself into Adobe Acrobat that is causing the crashes. EtreCheck will tell us the extensions/plugins/etc that are running on your Mac.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan I've added the requested Etre Check report.  I use the Apple mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't reinstall an operating system because one application is misbehaving. That doesn't really make any sense. This could just be a bug in Adobe's software. If there is a way to report bugs to Adobe I'd try that, I'm sure they'll be more interested in faults in their own software than Apple will be in what is to them third-party software.

Anyway.

The first thing I'd do is make sure I had all the latest updates installed. This could be a bug that someone has already reported and Adobe have fixed. It looks like you do have the latest version of Adobe Acrobat XI though.

The second thing I'd do is I would try the application within a new account. As you use an application is creates all kind of settings, cache, etc files throughout your account. Create a new account, which will essentially be starting from scratch without these files and see if it works reliably there without crashing. If it does then the case of the crashes are something within your own account.

The third thing would be to try cleaning up after the application in your own account. So locate all the files that Adobe Acrobat has created within your account and either delete or temporarily rename them (caches under /User/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Adobe..., preferences under /User/USERNAME/Library/Preferences, perhaps other files in something like /User/USERNAME/Library/Adobe, etc). And then try the application again. You can try this a step at a time, to try to identify which is causing the problem.

If there are a serious of steps you follow that reliably cause the application to crash, please update your question and we might be able to give a more specific answer.

Comment: I've edited the question to add more context as to what seems to trigger the crashes in Adobe.  The Finder crashes are rarer and I have not come up with any noticed patterns.

Comment: I would agree with Alistair. It is likely an Acrobat issue. yes you could re-image the Mac and it should fix it but with a little more investigating or at the very least ripping anything associated with Adobe off your system (prefs, cache, etc.) should get you the desired result without the pain of a re-image

Answer (score 0):

Besides the advice already given, have a good look at your fonts; a wonky font can cause Acrobat to misbehave.

There is also an utility available from Adobe (no, I don't have the link available right now), which does a deep cleaning of everything Acrobat; you might therefore consider running that tool and reinstall Acrobat.